# Array of integers with divisor

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck of something pretty basic. I need to take an array of integers and find if an integer n is divisible by the array of integers in a method called `divisibleIntegers`. The main method will print true if all are divisible.

I can create the array; But when I create the divisor expression I am a bit confused.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the code you have so far?

Comment: Use modular operator (%) to check if the given number is divisible by other number or not.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array, and if you find an element that does not divide with the denominator, return false. example:

```
boolean divisibleIntegers(int denom) {
    for (int elem : myArray) {
         if (elem % denom != 0)
              return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Dhinakaran Yes a compiler would help to find this bug... :)

Comment: `for (int i : myArray) {` Note that `i` is already the content of the array. `myArray[i]` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You should check all the elements of the array, if there exists one element that is not divisible by `n`, return `false`, otherwise (All elements are divisible by `n`), return `true`.

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) about the reminder operator.

```
public static boolean divisibleIntegers(int[] arr, int n) {
    for(int num : arr) {
        if (!(num % n)) {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

System.out.println(divisibleIntegers(new int[]{2,4,8}, 2)); //Will print true.
System.out.println(divisibleIntegers(new int[]{2,5,8}, 2)); //Will print false.
```